# What is the meaning of the symbol $\lesssim$?

Tags: definition, relations

I have encountered a symbol I do not understand the meaning of. I've searched tables online but to no avail.

[image: picture in this link]

The [picture in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kahja.png) (not enough points to embed yet) shows the symbol twice; 'masses $\gtrsim$ $10^{16}$ g' and 'energies $\gtrsim$ $10^{32}$ ergs'. What is the meaning of this symbol?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this means less than or similar to, like less than or equal to but more vague.

Comment: I assume it's a mix of `<` and `≈`. Is there a way to make sure this is the actual use case, or are there other definitions that can apply as well?

Comment: If the author just throws it there, without having defined it at some prior point, then It is simply bad notation. From what I can see in the link, it means "more than or at the order of magnitude of", but the more clear $\approx$ (approximately) or $\ge$ (more than or equal to) would perfectly do the job, so its just bad notation. I have seen it in the completely different context as  $A\lesssim B$ or $A\preceq B$ meaning "$A$ is less preferred than B", where it is a perfectly valid notation, but this has nothing to do with the text at hand.

Comment: Being a physics paper my guess is it's a statement about orders of magnitude.

Comment: Yup, physicist love to describe things by "order of magnitude".

Comment: greater than approximately